# How to remove block that appears instead of letters in kali linux firefox ESR to show clear letter?

Tags: firefox, fonts, kali-linux

I have tried every method that I could find but it didn't help me. See the image below and help me to solve the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I copied the URL into Firefox and viewed the source code for the page, I found that some of the blocks of text that are displaying with the funny characters are dates within a [span](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Span_and_div) tag. E.g., `<span class="f">May 12, 2014 - </span>`. When I viewed the page on a CentOS Linux system, I found that text where that span tag was applied was displayed with the Liberation Sans font. Within Firefox, you can see the font that is used by your system for a particular text block by highlighting the text by holding the left-mouse button down while dragging the mouse pointer over the text and then right-clicking once the area is highlighted and choosing **Inspect Element**, then in the Inspector window click on the **Fonts** tab in the right pane.

The [Liberation fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberation_fonts) are "metrically compatible with the most commonly used fonts on Microsoft Windows operating system and Office suite (Monotype Corporation's Arial, Arial Narrow, Times New Roman and Courier New, respectively), for which Liberation is intended as free substitute."  When I viewed the same page with Firefox on an OS X system, it displayed text within span tags using class "f" with the [Arial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial) font. Do you have either the Liberation sans font or Arial on your system? If not, try installing the [Liberation fonts](https://pagure.io/liberation-fonts) or Arial.

Instructions for installing Arial on a Kali Linux system can be found at [Install fonts on Linux – Debian, Ubuntu, Kali, Mint – Microsoft TrueType core and many more](https://www.blackmoreops.com/2014/07/31/install-fonts-on-linux/), which states that you can use the command `apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer` to install the Microsoft True Type Core Fonts for the Web.

Comment: but after restarting the laptop. same problem exists.What to do now?

Comment: @Nilesh, is Kali Linux installed on a hard disk drive/solid state drive within the computer or are you booting it from a [live CD or live DVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Livecd) or [live USB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_USB) flash drive?

Comment: It is installed on hard drive. I only have kali linux on my laptop(i.e no dual booting).